# c# service doesn't work when it called by another form

Tags: c#, forms, service, task

I have a service which send mail to my users. When I use "*Debugger.Break()*" to run service in the debugger, It works succesfully but when I run it on another form like :

```
ServiceController service = ServiceController.GetServices().Where(s => s.ServiceName == "ServiceA").FirstOrDefault();

if (service != null)
{
    if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) service.Start();
}
```

It opens service what means I can see my service in task manager but codes doesn't work. Codes have eventlog entries but I can't see any error messages in event viewer. So It means codes doesn't run when I call this service on another form. Is there any permission fail? I tried something about that but I can't fix this. What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in your code and then in the debug menu, using "Attach To Process" option. That way you can step through your code and see what fails.

Comment: I'm using Debugger.Break() when app starts. So I can see what fails but program has no errors. Did you mean that when running on another process?

Comment: Yeah, install the service on your local machine, start it and then in VS use attach to process. It will then step in to your code when it hits a  breakpoint allowing you to debug like any other app

Comment: can you help me about that? I'm not familiar for this. If you have skype : oceanjack35, really I need this help. I think you are good in this section.

Comment: Not really able to skype. You need to just step into your start method and see what is happening with it. You can start the service on your local machine and use debug-->attach to process

Comment: I thought by "Another form" he meant, not in debug mode rather than an actual form...good point tho

Comment: I tried to install this now because I didn't know it requires to install. I install this with prompt(with InstallUtil.exe) and I got this error:

"Service Control Manager cannot open in "." machine. It may require other permissions." How can I change permissions?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do now. It may be a permissions issue. There is some info here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548369/NTRemoteProcessControl-Enumerate-and-control-Windo

Comment: @AliAvcı - you should be administrator to install. Try right clicking on the command prompt icon in the start menu, and select run as administrator. Then run the install from that command window.

Comment: I run as admin command prompt but now it says "This service already exist". I deleted service on regedit. Where can I delete fully this service and re-install?

Comment: InstallUtil for deleting it and creating it. Messing with the registry to remove it is not a great idea

Comment: Woww james and hatchet.you were reallty much help me and I solved my fails. So user should install service first and I should create an installer for this. So my last fail is how can I create an installer of the service? :)